# Progress bar in TweenMax

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am watching this https://codepen.io/alexandrebuffet/pen/wYvEGK

When it starts, the progress bar should be only in the "active".
If u watch the frst, second and third, all its ok.
But, when you watch the 2º slide for the second time, the 1º slide progress bar is working as well at the same time.

Why?

```
// Animate pagination
      this.DOM.paginationItemsLoader = paginationEl.querySelectorAll('.pagination-separator-loader');
      this.DOM.activePaginationItem = paginationEl.querySelector('.slideshow-pagination-item.active');
      this.DOM.activePaginationItemLoader = this.DOM.activePaginationItem.querySelector('.pagination-separator-loader');

      console.log(swiper.pagination);
      // console.log(swiper.activeIndex);

      // Reset and animate
        TweenMax.set(this.DOM.paginationItemsLoader, {scaleX: 0});
        TweenMax.to(this.DOM.activePaginationItemLoader, this.config.slideshow.pagination.duration, {
          startAt: {scaleX: 0},
          scaleX: 1,
        });


    }

}

const slideshow = new Slideshow(document.querySelector('.slideshow'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `console.log()` inside of the `animatePagination` function and see that the function is being called twice each time on the second run through. Fix that and it will fix your issue.